# Sphinx frequency ranking

Tags: sphinx

I have read sphinx documentation and cant find an answer.

I have a sphinx index set up on 2 fields (title, description)

I would like ranking to be higher the more times a search term is present in one or both of the fields. For example: A search for "car"

```
Product A:
Title: Red car
Desc: good car


Product B:
Title: Green car
Desc: A really good car. The best car.
```

In the above example I would like product B to rank higher than A because "car" is present 2 times in its description. Currently they two items are ranked equally.

What settings do i need to adjust in Sphinx to get this to work?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and simple way would be to use SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT

But you could get better results by using a custom ranker
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expression-ranker
eg with word_count or maybe hit_count.